# Correctly formatting arrays in HTML

Tags: html, ruby, erb

I'm currently scraping product information from a website and am attempting to output it into a table on a webpage.

I'm stuck because the only code that I can get to properly format as

```
ITEM
IMAGE
PRICE
```

Is clearly wrong, and ends up replicating the data many times.

The partially functioning code is:

> ```
>   <table>
>     <tr>
>       <% @items.each do |title| %>
>       <% @images.each do |image| %>
>       <% @prices.each do |price| %>
>       <br>
>       <td><%= title %></td>
>       <br>
>       <td><%= image %></td>
>       <br>
>       <td><%= price %></td></tr>
>       <br>
>   </table>
>   <% end %>
>   <% end %>
>   <% end %>
> ```

I've tried formatting the code like below, but it tends to drop the three sets of data down like

```
TITLE TITLE TITLE IMAGE IMAGE IMAGE PRICE PRICE PRICE.
```

in a variety of very incorrect ways.

> ```
>  <table>
>    <tr>
>      <td>
>        <% @items.each do |title| %>
>        <%= title %>
>        <% end %>
>      </td>
>      <br>
>      <td>
>        <% @images.each do |image| %>
>        <%= image %>
>        <% end %>
>      <br>
>      <td>
>        <% @prices.each do |price| %>
>        <%= price %>
>        <% end %>
>      </td>
>      <br>
>   </table>
> ```

Is anyone able to spot the mistake I'm making or know what I need to do to properly output this code? Do I need to show you any more code?

Comment: Why is this a Nokogiri question? Because it's used in some other part of your program? You're using ERB templates, so your tags should include ERB and possibly Rails, if you're using Rails, and not mention Nokogiri, because nothing in the code or data refers to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the three arrays together you need to [`zip`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip) them. This will enable you to render each triplet together (the first item with the first image and the first price; the second item with the second image and the second price; etc.):

```
  <table>
    <% @items.zip(@images, @prices).each do |title, image, price| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= title %></td>
      <td><%= image %></td>
      <td><%= price %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
```